# Magento: how to add a new backend php form

Tags: php, magento, module, backend

I would appreciate any input here.

I have some php code that I've developed to import a csv file into a custom table in the Magento db and then compare this data with data in the sales_flat_order table and display a simple report.

I now need to add a link to this page in the Magento backend so the guys using the  backend can find and use it easily.

I have a bit of experience with adding new Magento modules, but I was wondering if there is any easier way to just add the Magento backend look and feel to my php pages and add a new menu item linking to them?

It seems like a big bloated exercise to have to have to go through the process of adding a Magento module and to have to re-code everything now that its already done.

Any help would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just pop your link in the header links - header.phtml in admin template folders. Job done, not elegant but why spend any longer on it?

Comment: Thanks Matt, my feelings exactly!